# Read CSV file and store specific columns

Tags: python, csv

- **Cannot use pandas, as module installation is restricted.**

A CSV file has to be read and grouped based on 1st column and store 2nd and 3rd column values.

```
$cat Credentials.csv 
Type,Username,Password
Unix,Raju,qwe
Middleware,Anku,asd
Database,Trigun,zxc
Unix,Priti,poi
Middleware,Sheetal,lkj
```

Based on the type, in specific paths the username and password vaules have to be lopped for further process,
Ex: For Unix, change working path to /some_path/Unix/ and then loop two rows.

```
import csv

#declare list / set
type=set()
master=[]

with open ('/Users/anku/Documents/dev/Credentials.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig')as csv_input:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_input)
    next(csv_file)

    #get unique value of system types
    for row in csv_file:
        type.add(row[0])
    print(type)

    #back to top of the csv file
    csv_input.seek(0)

    #
    for types in type:
        print("The value: " + types )
        nested = []
        for row in csv_file:
            if row[0] == types:
                nested.append(row[1:3])
        print(nested)
        master.append(nested)
        csv_input.seek(0)
    print(master)
```

output:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/python3 /Users/anku/Documents/dev/ReadFilesCSV.py
{'Middleware', 'Database', 'Unix'}
The value: Middleware
[['Anku', 'asd'], ['Sheetal', 'lkj']]
The value: Database
[['Trigun', 'zxc'], ['Kunal', 'mnb']]
The value: Unix
[['Raju', 'qwe'], ['Priti', 'poi']]
[[['Anku', 'asd'], ['Sheetal', 'lkj']], [['Trigun', 'zxc'], ['Kunal', 'mnb']], [['Raju', 'qwe'], ['Priti', 'poi']]]
bash-3.2$
```

I am trying to get into a list but stuck on how to loop them through individual types.
Cannot use pandas as module installation is restricted. Only with the use of default installed modules.
Questions:

Can we create list names based on the elements of the set.

```
type[0]=[] # Middleware =[]
```

Any suggestion or efficient way to solve this.

Comment: Your code already seems to do what is needed. Can you explicitly specify the output you want?

Comment: everytime i run my script, the set order changes, and so does the master list, then i cannot fetch from the mater list again

Comment: [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are not ordered. _A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements._ Convert the set to a list and order it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Trenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108354/read-csv-file-and-store-specific-columns?noredirect=1#comment113365853_64108354),

> [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are not ordered. A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Convert the set to a list and order it

Or you could use an [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which remembers the order you set its keys, and do everything in one loop.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict()
with open('/Users/anku/Documents/dev/Credentials.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_input:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_input)
    next(csv_file)

    #get unique value of system types
    for row in csv_file:
        row_type = row[0]
        row_data = row[1:]
        # if the dict doesn't already have the key, set it to an empty list
        if not row[0] in data:
            data[row_type] = []
        data[row_type].append(row_data)
```

Then you can see the data in the order you added it:

```
print(data.keys()) # Should print the keys in the order they were added
print(data.items())
```